# hide iframe url in HTML source code

Tags: iframe

How to hide iframe url From HTML source code?

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="728" height="90"></iframe>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to do this because there is a param in the url I don't want exposed on the client

Answer (score 13):

You can use javascript to load the source, and it will not be visible in `iframe url` in page source code.
For example with `jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('iframe').attr('src','http://www.flickr.com/');
});
</script>

<body>
<iframe src="" />
</body>
```

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/65ytY/)

You can combine it with `$.post` to get the value serverside:

```
$.post('get-iframe-src.php', function(data) {
  $('iframe').attr('src',data);
});
```

You can even load `iframe` itself to some element like:

```
$.post('get-iframe.php', function(data) {
  $('#element_id').html(data);
});
```

etc. solutions are many, this is just one of.

Comment: That wont be enough:

http://jsbin.com/suqupanume/edit?html,js,console,output

When you use jquery, or for that matter, javascript to change the iframe attribute, it will become visible for those who inspect the iframe.

Answer (score 8):

You can't.  If the URL isn't in the HTML, how would the browser know where to get it?

One thing you could try is to obscure it to make it *slightly harder* for someone to find it.  You could have the `src` attribute be blank and then when the document is ready fetch the URL value from the server in a separate AJAX request and update the `iframe` tag to include that value in the `src`.

This would be a fair amount of work, however, and wouldn't really accomplish anything.  The only thing it would prevent is somebody finding it by viewing the page source.  They can still look at the "current version" of the HTML in any web browser's debugging tools.  (Right click on an element and inspect it, which is nearly ubiquitous at this point.)  Or any other normal traffic-sniffing tools will see it plain as day.

Ultimately, if the web browser needs to know a piece of information, then that information needs to be visible on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I decided for solution that does not use javascript, because most of the time it will be possible to read the "hidden" content.

Moreover, changing iframe SRC with javascript, will keep URL hidden when checking the source. However, inspecting the code will show the real URL.

My code is in PHP; however, I believe that the logic can be translated to other programming languages. This is how it works:

I kept the iframe tag as usual:

```
<iframe src="dash_url.php"></iframe>
```

The trick is inside the iframe_url.php, where I validate the referer. If it is valid, page is redirected to iframe URL. If it is not, than URL will be a message.

```
<?
$iframe_url = "https://example.com";

$Referer = @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$RefererHost = @explode(":", explode("/", explode("//", $Referer)[1])[0])[0];

if ($RefererHost == $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) {
    header("Location: " . $iframe_url);
} else {
    echo "Invalid URL";
}
?>
```

If visitor inspects the page or checks the source, iframe tag will show SRC as dash_url.php.

Comment: It is actually a good solution~ it gets the url on server side.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fully block source viewing. But there are a couple ways to disable right-clicking:

1) Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var message="Your message goes here.";

function click(e) {
if (document.all) {
if (event.button == 2) {
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
if (document.layers) {
if (e.which == 3) {
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}
if (document.layers) {
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
}
document.onmousedown=click;
// -->
```

2) Add the following into your  tag: oncontextmenu="return false"

reference `https://forum.powweb.com/archive/index.php/t-36161.html`