# asp.net pulling external web page while preventing client from seeing requests

Tags: asp.net, server, server-side

I'm facing a security issue where my users can see all url from where i pull content from,
I use a third party dashboard app with 4 html pages showing system status for each company .'www.xyz.com/dashboard/x.html'

I would like to create new 'aspx' file and display the 'x.html' inside as plain text , while preventing the user to see where the x.html is downloaded from , because he should not have access to the other 'html' files under the same domain. 
[here, the user should not see the xhr and where they come from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jFA7.png)

In other meaning , I need to create an asynchronous server side request that brings the 'x.html' and displaying it's content inside my aspx as it was my page.

Comment: I'd change the format of the question. What are you trying? What are you expecting? What is going wrong? If your problem is just that clients can see you've `iframe`d something, that's not an error, it's working as designed and that's a basic security feature of the internet.

Comment: Hi Chaim Eliyah thanks for your reply ,
Let's say your browsing into my website,
I'd like to display you an external web page , without letting you know where it comes from .
It means even when i embed it inside 'div' or 'iframe' ,when going to the developer tool section, you will be able to see what url i'm pulling the data from , and this is what i want to prevent you from seeing .
Hope i was clear

Comment: As I said, you can't disable that. It's a security feature. What's to keep me from sending you to a malicious link? You'll notice you also can't disable displaying the target of `<a>` elements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547730/hide-iframe-url-in-html-source-code) for details about how to manipulate the mouse controls.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah, I understand what you mean, but what if i want to display you a 'test.html' page : www.xyz.com/test.html , without letting you know the domain name in order to prevent from you accessing some other pages in the same domain.

Comment: You can't control routing or authentication on an external domain. That's just not how the internet works.

Comment: thought about decomposing the page, rendering it and re-desplay it as it was my web page

Comment: You can copy HTML, sure, and if it was _yours_ you wouldn't even be plagiarizing....

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

If *you* have an ASP.NET Dashboard app with multiple pages and you want to restrict access, you need to implement [ASP.NET Identity role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles) so that your clients who login only have access to the areas of the site you want them to access.

On the other hand if you are trying to take someone else's HTML page and display it as your own, that goes against our [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and you should instead consider openly redirecting your users to the proper page and giving credit where it's due.

Original answer: You can't do this, for two reasons:

1. The browser must know the target URL.
2. Obscuring the target URL would be a violation of basic security principles.

The `<iframe>` element requires a `src` attribute. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for comprehensive documentation.

Comment: is there a way to request an external web page asynchronously and then display it back in my web page?

Comment: by rendering it as a view? I suppose if it's a text-only web page, it's possible. if it contains references to any images or scripts on the external domain, you'd lose all referential integrity. you'd have to iterate through the tags and fix the broken references.

without more information in your question about the problem you're trying to solve, I'm afraid it sounds more like an <iframe> question than a question about ASP.NET MVC. MVC is not a framework for displaying external pages; it's a framework for creating your own.

Comment: ChaimEliyah , I appreciate your answer and will clarify my answer the most i can . 
I have a dashboard containing 4 pages. i would like to embed one of them in a new website in order to give it to a new user . 
But I'm affraid the user will get access to the other pages and therefore i want to prevent from him from seeing what domain  the content was downloaded from.

Comment: Yeah give the question an edit and I'll check it in the morning. It sounds like what you want is role-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles

Comment: I read your edit. I'm afraid I can't help you any further. It may be a language issue but what you're trying to do honestly sounds quite wrong.